# How to join a Windows Domain and Map Network Drives?

Tags: networking, email, active-directory

I just installed the current build for Ubuntu on a partition for my work computer. I am a novice when it comes to Linux/Ubuntu, which is why I installed it along side windows. I want to learn how to operate and use Ubuntu much more than I do now, so I figured installing it and trying to do day to day functions here would be a "Thrown into the pool with sharks" way to do it, and I like that way.

I did however have a few questions:

- We are on a Domain in Windows, is there any way to join that domain using the Ubuntu partition?
- We Also have 16 mapped network drives. I don't actually need ALL of them mapped for Ubuntu, but is there a way to Map at least one of them to see/use here in Ubuntu.
- Outlook Corporate email, how can I sign in/use it while...well, you get the idea.

As I said earlier, I am VERY new to Ubuntu, i've only played around with it a bit at home and never at the office. If you could simplify it down for me a bit, that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here goes!

- **Windows Domain** - A popular solution for adding an Ubuntu machine to a Windows domain is Likewise-Open, found here: http://www.likewise.com/products/likewise_open/ It's quite possible that there are other alternatives out there; this was the first one I stumbled upon.
- **Mapping Drives** - As to mapping drives, Ubuntu has the functionality already built in. Just go to the "start" menu, go to "Places," and select "Connect to Server..." In the dialog, make sure you select "Windows share" from the "Service type" drop-down box, and then fill in the rest of the info.
- **Outlook E-mail** - The already-installed Evolution Mail application should be what you're looking for. Now, there's funny business afoot with Microsoft Exchange servers, so if your company uses one for its mail, you may or may not run into problems (it depends on the version of the server, amongst other things). From the Exchange section of the Evolution documentation: "*Evolution Exchange works only with Exchange 2000 and later, and requires that Outlook Web Access be enabled. Each user needs a valid Microsoft Exchange server account, including a license.*" On the other hand, if your company uses standard IMAP/POP mail, you shouldn't have any trouble. (And perhaps someone more knowledgeable than myself can chime in about that Exchange stuff; I'm terribly behind the times with mail clients!)

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

For the Outlook E-mail problem it is also possible to use DavMail ( http://davmail.sourceforge.net/ ) in combination with Thunderbird. It works great if your company is using Exchange.

For this also Outlook Web Access must be enabled.

I used Evolution myself, but it crashed a lot. I had lots of problems. Since I use DavMail with Thunderbird I don't have any problems anymore.
If you use the extensions "Lightning" and "Inverse SOGo Connector" you can also use the Calendar and Contacts. The only thing you can't use are the notes.